# How to enable or disable a combo box based on a radio button's value C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple stupid question but I just can get the hang of it...So i have a form in C#, with a combo box button and also a radio button. I want when selected a value from radio button that the combo box to be disabled, if not the combo box to be enabled...

Any hints?
Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

if you want to `Enable/Disable` Combobox based on the `RadioButton` Checked status you can check for `Checked` property of the `RadioButton` and Enable/Disable the `Combobox`.

`Checked` Property returns the `boolean` value, so if it is `true` you can `disable` the `ComboBox` .

if it is `false` you can `Enable` the `ComboBox`.

Note : Handle the `RadioButton` `CheckedChanged` Event to handle it properly.
Try This :

```
 private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           if (radioButton1.Checked)
                comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            else
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
     }
```

Comment: If you ever have if/else statements that only differ in a `false`/`true` constant, you should probably rewrite it to be a single, simple statement (like Satal's answer)

Comment: @TimS.: Yes :) that is very simple, but both works in same way IMO, and if i change my answer both looks same :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest subscribing to the radioButton checked change event, then as Sudhakar suggested update the combo box enabled property according to what you want to happen.

So for example;

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Enabled = !radioButton1.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.binding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to acheive this.

The result may look like this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Enabled", radioButton1, "Checked", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }
```